# How to cause buffer overflow in interpreter?

Tags: python, buffer, buffer-overflow

How to cause buffer overflow in interpreter?Let's say in python for example.

I have searched in Google but I am not finding tutorial on how to do it.I only read somewhere that is possible wit python or java interpreter to cause buffer overflow

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/261171/do-high-level-languages-allow-for-buffer-heap-overflow

Comment: Unless there's a bug in the Python interpreter, it shouldn't be possible. Unlike C, Python knows the length of its buffers and automatically checks indexes against the length. If you try to access outside a buffer you get an error.